# How to edit the index page of wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Here's my problem.
I want to edit the index page of a wordpress theme. I want to edit the actual page that loads in the browser. When i open inspect element on chrome i get html code but when i go to editor in the admin pannel, at the index.php i have php code. Here's why:
I want to edit this webpage cypherbeats.com and instead of that background video i want to but something like this:http://themes.cray.bg/themeswitch/?theme=Storyline%203D%20Slider
i know how to develop this carousell but i don't know where to put it on the theme. In admin panel i don't see the html that loads in browser.
Any idea?

Comment: The index.php page generates html depending on the functions used in it. For example `get_header();` injects the content found in the header.php file into the page.

Comment: ok, but from where? the database? inside tabels of database is html code? can i edit it? from where?

Comment: Most files are inside the theme folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to learn how WordPress works. Start with https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

> Template files are the building blocks of your WordPress site. They
>   fit together like the pieces of a puzzle to generate the web pages on
>   your site. Some templates (the header and footer template files for
>   example) are used on all the web pages, while others are used only
>   under specific conditions.

and read https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

> WordPress Themes live in subdirectories of the WordPress themes
>   directory (wp-content/themes/ by default) which cannot be directly
>   moved using the wp-config.php file. The Theme's subdirectory holds all
>   of the Theme's stylesheet files, template files, and optional
>   functions file (functions.php), JavaScript files, and images. For
>   example, a Theme named "test" would reside in the directory
>   wp-content/themes/test/. Avoid using numbers for the theme name, as
>   this prevents it from being displayed in the available themes list.

and, for adding Javascript scripts like a slider or carousel to a theme, read https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Or simply use a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

Just check the header.php file you can find the code written for revolution slider, remove that code and put your slider code that you want to show on in place of the video

Comment: Otherwise go to plugin and remove revolution slider and install your slider instead and put the shortcode into your header section. Or go to revolution slider, edit slide and do changes as per your requirement.